# adding the user to a many to many field upon creating a model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Good day, I am trying to create a viewset whereby when a showcase is created, the user gets added as one of the administrators in the many to many fields, but my code doesn't seem to work. Below is what I have tried, which doesn't work.

models.py

```
class Showcase(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    skill_type = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="Showcases")
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="upvotes")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    administrator = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="administrators", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
class showcaseCreateViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Showcase.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShowcaseSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, administrator=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py

```
class ShowcaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='slug')
    created_on = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    user_has_voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    comment_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Showcase
        exclude = ['voters', 'updated_on', 'id', 'administrator']

    def get_likes_count(self, instance):
        return instance.voters.count()

    def get_user_has_voted(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return instance.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()

    def get_comment_count(self, instance):
        return instance.comments.count()
```

Comment: Can you include the serializer itself?  You could do this as the answer suggests, or have a custom `create` on the serializer itself which gets the request.user and does it there.

Comment: I just added the serializers @AndrewBacker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be an alternative, instead of overwriting `perform_create`, overwrite `create`

```
class showcaseCreateViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Showcase.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShowcaseSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            showcase = serializer.save(user=request.user)
            if showcase:
                showcase.administrator.add(request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Another possibility is passing in the view the request (or just the user) to the context of the serializer by implementing `get_serializer_context`,

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {
        'request': self.request
    }
```

and then, implement the `create` method of the serializer,

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    showcase = Showcase(**validated_data)
    showcase.administrator.add(self.context['request'].user)
    showcase.save()
    return showcase
```

Comment: Glad it help you